# extract vs excerpt

Tags: difference, vocabulary

This question seems to be tricky even for native speakers. I have done a quick search on Google and gotten mixed results. However, the best result I have gotten so far is from [iTalki.com](http://www.italki.com/question/264925):

> They are pretty much synonyms. I see that m-w.com lists each as a
>   synonym for the other.
>
> TO ME, "excerpt" SUGGESTS a long passage that is intended to be read,
>   possibly for enjoyment, as a coherent whole. An example would be an
>   entire book chapter--for example, a whole chapter of a new book
>   published in a magazine.
>
> TO ME, an "extract" is usually shorter than an "excerpt" but longer
>   than a "quotation."

The sense I am interested in is when used to deal with *text* whether it is a book, essay, transcript, poem etc.

Some criteria you could think about giving the best answer is:

- Length (which one is longer in general)
- Collocations (I really want to know if there is, and hopefully get some examples)
- Register (academic, governmental, legal, entertainment and spoken English)

Answer (score 1):

As nouns, *excerpt* and *extract* are synonymous, i.e. a small piece of a longer text.

In respect to texts, I suspect *excerpt* would be the more common of the two, mainly because the verb *to extract* has a much wider range of meanings.  One can extract ore, or extract the truth, or extract a tooth; but text is the only thing one can excerpt.

Comment: Actually, extract is fairly common in ELL books. However, I will cite from an ELT website instead. "Want to hear more about Pan Macmillan business books?
Sign up for great extra content and **free extracts from books** by leading business minds.". And, "Drawing on Eastern and Western philosophy, and colourful characters from Picasso and Socrates to Warren Beatty, this book represents a lifetime of wisdom learned at the creative cutting edge.

[Click here for **a short extract**](http://www.panmacmillan.com/devpanmacmillan/media/panmacmillan/PDF-Extracts/Predatory_Thinking_sample.pdf)"

Comment: The quotes above were taken from [Macmillan's website](http://www.panmacmillan.com/businessbooks)

Comment: Did I say *extract* was uncommon?

Comment: No you didn't, but I felt it wouldn't be common when I read your answer. When I study the reading sections in ELL books I have used I usually come across the word "extract" being used, that is if not always.

Comment: You cannot judge word frequency by one book. In any case, you can use them interchangeably.